# im trying to install pywin32 but get not such file or directory

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pyhook and putting !-- python.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.py -install !-- in the cmd but I get !-- Can't open file 'python.exe Scripts\pywin32_postinstall.': [errno 2] No such file or directory !--. I have a x64 bit pc and I installed python 3.4.3. the path is set to !-- c:\python34;C:\Python34\tools\Scripts !--

so I'm trying to figure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Install `pywin32-219.win-amd64-py3.4.exe` from http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20219/

Comment: it tells me invalid syntax and pointing to the c at the very beginning of what you told me @cgohlke.